# xpages set the hover property for viewPanel rows

Tags: css, xpages

I use this style sheet:

```
.oddRow {
 ...
}
```

And then I use these in the `rowClasses` property:

```
<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1" viewStyle="width:100.0%"
        rowClasses="evenRow, oddRow" var="rowData" 
......
```

I would like to use :

```
.evenrow:Hover {  }
```

but I don't know how to use/declare it in my above style sheet.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the wrong "even" row class in your rowClasses property. You refer to oddEven but your style sheet contains a class called evenrow. So do this instead:

```
rowClasses="oddRow, evenRow"
```

**Update**

The hover part should only be part of your CSS - not your rowClasses property. Make sure to name the CSS classes the same in your rowClasses property and in your stylesheet (that you obviously need to include on your page).

So change your rowClasses to:

```
rowClasses="oddRow, evenRow"
```

and your CSS to:

```
.oddRow {
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: RGB(248, 248, 248);
}
.evenRow {
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: RGB(255, 255, 255); 
}
.evenRow:hover {
 background-color: rgb(288, 250, 221);
}
```

Comment: I think it was a typo mistake. I corrected the question.

Comment: Still not working... :( It works on categorized views, as well, right? I just changed the rgb to a more obvious color: rgb(255,255,0). I just move the mouse over on the respective rows, but no success for me...

Comment: It does. If you use Chrome, then start Developer Tools and inspect whether your CSS load, and if the classes are somehow overriden by some other more specific CSS selector. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

According to the declaration of your viewport, you can use the CSS like below.

```
.oddRow
{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: RGB(248, 248, 248);
}
.oddEven
{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: RGB(255, 255, 255); 
}
.oddEven:hover
{
 background-color: rgb(288, 250, 221);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did use & declare the above CSS to my viewPanel, but the Hover isn't shown. I will edit my question and add 'xpages' to the tags, I think I'm missing something.